# Bass guitar amp power socket issues

Tags: maintenance, amplifiers, instrument-care

I have a rather unusual question. I have a Fender Affinity Jazz Bass starter kit and it comes with a 15W amp - "Rumble 15 Bass Combo Amp".

I also have a cat in the house, and every time I don't cover my amp with a plastic bag, my amp becomes an instant scratching post. However, to cover the amp between each practice session, I have to unplug/plug my power cord into the amp every time I use it.

The problem is, the plug socket is unusually tight, really tight. I'm not a big guy, but I'm not weak by any means either. Yet it takes me quite a lot of effort just to plug and unplug it. I'm not sure how to quantize the level of effort so you guys understand, but lets just say if I try to unplug I *have* to use two hands, I *have* to always start by wiggling the plug out, and my body even moves back a bit after I finally pull it out.

I don't think this is usual, and I think the wiggling has been damaging the bass amp. I believe the amp just happened to be manufactured with a not-too-good socket. So my questions are:

- Is there anything I can do to make the socket less tight or make it easier to plug/unplug?
- or... how would you keep your cat away from the amp?

UPDATE: Turns out it's a cable problem as Chocos suggested... the material for the cable plug is very stiff and probably not exactly the right size and I'm pretty sure the cable's made in china. I've also cut a little slot in the bag to slide over the cable. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: have you tried using a different cable?

Comment: @Chochos that's a good point, don't know why I didn't think of trying that

Comment: How about using a different cat? :-)   No, actually, mod the cover so it fits over/around the cord.

Answer (score 2):

Cats and scratching... yeah, I can relate.

A great way to get the cat to stop it is to drape duct-tape, sticky side out, all over the sides where the cat likes to scratch. The second the cat gets sticky tape on its paws it'll change its mind about how fun it is to scratch that particular "post" and will leave it alone.

This doesn't hurt the cat at all; They hate anything stuck to their feet, so it will drive it nuts.

This same trick works for cats jumping on furniture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the cat enjoys clawing the speaker mesh. Try leaving the amp. facing down on the floor. Is the socket a kettle plug sort ?

Comment: Yep, it's the kettle plug. The cat enjoys the fuzzy wood panels of it unfortunately. =/

Comment: Cat or amp. Amp or cat...

Comment: Cat conditioning - every time it scratches it, play a loud discordant set of notes :-) (note this is actually a joke. I wouldn't really condone torture of animals through music. Well, there is opera, I suppose...)

Comment: kettle plugs are available in right-angled form, both to the side and downwards. You may be able to slip the cover over then. Alternatively, I can recommend a lovely cats' home...

Answer (score 1):

We've had some success - not on music gear (that stays behind closed doors) - but on walls by taping tin foil (aluminum foil) to the walls.  The cats hate the sound of it, and I think they don't like how it feels.

Plus it looks *excellent*.